# bootstrap modal is opening a second modal instead of do anything

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i have two modal, both with data-backdrop="false" and if i click modal1 and then click modal2 is opening me the modal2 too instead of don't do anything.
here an example:

Here's an inline link to JsFiddle.

Comment: Excuse me, but i don't see the link...  ?

Comment: Please edit your post and provide the jsfiddle link.